# Show Plymouth Boot Screen error after mounting tmpfs on /etc/fstab

Tags: cgroups, tmpfs, rhel9

Encountered the error after reboot: "Show Plymouth Boot Screen".
Anyone know which step or configuration I missed out?

I'm tried to mount tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup, and reboot.
Below are the screenshot of mounting tmpfs:

[image]

[image]

Note: I'm using RHEL 9.0